# Linq to CSV DateTime format using C#

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, csv

I have a huge CSV file with columns like this.

col1;col2

2013-12-17 15.52.35;1,09

2013-12-17 16.52.35;2,09

2013-12-17 17.52.35;3,09

I am trying to print the first column but it wont due to a different date/time format. However it prints the column in format 2013-12-17 15:52:35.

```
public class LinqData
{
    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 1)]
    public DateTime col1 { get; set; }

    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 2)]
    public float col2 { get; set; }
}

public class LinqToCSV
{
    public static IEnumerable<LinqData> somefunction()
   {
       var inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
        {
            SeparatorChar = ';',
            MaximumNbrExceptions = -1,
            FileCultureName = "sv-SE"
        };


        CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();

        IEnumerable<LinqData> CSVelements =
            cc.Read<LinqData>(@"C:\sample.csv", inputFileDescription);
        return CSVelements;
    }

   public LinqToCSV()
    {
        var inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
        {
            SeparatorChar = ';',
            MaximumNbrExceptions = -1,
            FileCultureName = "sv-SE"
        };
        CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();

        IEnumerable<LinqData> CSVelements =
            cc.Read<LinqData>(@"C:\sample.csv", inputFileDescription);

        var CSVelementNames = from p in CSVelements
                              orderby p.col1
                              select new { p.col1, p.col2 };

        foreach (var item in CSVelementNames) { Console.WriteLine(item); }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the kind help.

Comment: Question is not clear! can you explain lil more

Comment: use format and culture when you print your date

Answer (score 0):

If you want output datetime value for specific culture you can use [DateTime.ToString Method (IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ht77y576%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this

```
....
foreach (var item in CSVelementNames) { 
    Console.WriteLine("DateTime:{0}, Value:{1}",
    item.col1.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE").DateTimeFormat), 
    item.col2); 
}
....
```

if you want output only date so you can use [DateTime.ToShortDateString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
foreach (var item in CSVelementNames) { 
    Console.WriteLine("Date:{0}",
    item.col1.ToShortDateString()); 
}
```

Or use your custom format string like this

```
foreach (var item in CSVelementNames) { 
    Console.WriteLine("Date:{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss}",item.col1); 
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that did not work. I am using the tutorial from here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library#OutputFormat

Comment: what is concrete did not work? it sample output datetime in format for selected culture, in this case `sv-SE`, which format you want for datetime output?

Comment: The "col1" has a format "2013-12-17 15.52.35". I want it to print it that way as it is. I assumed it to be sv-SE format but that is not helping i guess. but if i change the format to "15:52:35" it prints without any error.

Comment: can you provide expected output for your sample?

Comment: col1= 2013-12-17 15.52.35, col2= 1,09

Comment: and what you have now?

Comment: @Muzab try last sample from my answer

Comment: Thanks a ton Grundy! I am sure your code will work but I am suspecting a bug in "LINQToCSV".I am reverting changes in the CSV itself and that will work. For further reference. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: @Muzab i think when you try output datetime variable to console, it don't depends on _LINQToCSV_

Comment: I suspect this part.                                  [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 1)]                                            
    public DateTime col1 { get; set; }  I dont have a plausible reason yet but hope i figure it out.

Comment: @Muzab i think it must work when you use something like method `write` from `CSVContext` but when you output datetime to console you must specify format manualy